# Chromecast receiver (CAF) multi audio issue

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, caf-receiver-sdk

I create a new receiver for my iOS application.
I have a video (DRM) with a few audios and text tracks
If I change audio track nothing will happen.
IF I change it manually like audioTracksManager.setActiveById(event.activeTrackIds[1]); - audio changed, but the button for changing tracks will be disabled
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by useLegacyDashSupport: true